# Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'abBackground'

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm using `ActionBarSherlock`, and want to use a custom background for both the ActionBar and the content view below it. When I try this, the background fills the whole screen, including the actionbar:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background</item>
</style>
```

So, from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9162297/675383), I tried to add `abBackground` to the theme:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background</item>
    <item name="abBackground">@drawable/bg_button_idle</item>
</style>
```

However, I get the error

> Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'abBackground'.

Why is this, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's how you can change the actionbar background:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
    <item name="background">@drawable/your_custom_drawable</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/your_custom_drawable</item>
</style>
```

Comment: You need an `android:background` item in the action bar style as well for ICS+.

Answer (score 0):

//there is no abBackground

```
 <item name="abBackground">@drawable/bg_button_idle</item>
```

//try

```
<item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_button_idle</item>
```

Comment: Using background f*s up the whole layout, so that is not an option.

Comment: If you use Benito answer it doesn't.

Answer (score -2):

if the project is a library module you shou check the Library module [image]

Comment: Not sure what youre trying to say here, this surely is not an answer to the question

Comment: sorry，I through it was your main modules can not find your library modules src。